# Compressing a PDF after the fact with Delphi

Tags: delphi, pdf, compression, delphi-2006, lossless-compression

I have apps that use routines for producing PDF's that use a thing called PDF-in-the-box.  The PDF's are not compressed, and there appears to be no way of achieving that with this component.  Rave components implement a compression event handler and I have used this successfully in other apps that were designed from the ground up with Rave.  I'd rather not recode the PDF-in-the-box stuff.  Is there any way with Delphi that I can compress a PDF after I have produced it.

(This not image compression - this is lossless compression of the PDF contents.  It results in a 3-fold decrease in PDF size typically).

I can simulate the effect I want by opening the PDFs produced with PDF-in-the-box in Adobe Reader and saving them again.  The re-saved PDFs are much smaller.  I just want to do the same thing in code.

Comment: Thanks @David.  That would mean recoding, but I'm wondering if rather than recoding the app to use another PDF library, a better approach would be to use SynPDF to post-process the uncompressed PDF after it had been generated - i.e. a routine written using SynPDF that did nothing more than read in the PDF and then spit it out again with compression enabled.  That's likely to be a simpler approach, yes?

Comment: That's what I had in mind. Better would be to only code once, but re-coding may be an expedient compromise.

Comment: @David, from my brief look at SynPDF, it can't read them anyway, only produces them.

Answer (score 0):

If using external tools from commandline isn't a problem, you can try:

- [Ghostscript](http://www.ghostscript.com/) -dPDFSETTINGS option (which unfortunately isn't well [documented](https://superuser.com/questions/435410/where-are-ghostscript-options-switches-documented))
- [QPDF](http://qpdf.sourceforge.net/) --stream-data=compress option.

QPDF seems to work faster for me.